# Unable to make Mono to emit a value

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Setup in brief:

```
       var initValue = getValue()
        if (null == initValue) {
            // getValFromService() returns a Mono<SomeObject>
            val response = service.getValFromService()
            println("Checkpoint 1")
            response.log().subscribe {
                println("Checkpoint 2")
                initValue = it.value
            }
        }
        println("Checkpoint 3")

// I need the value to make this call but I always end up getting null
callAnotherService(value)
```

I'm expecting(I need) output to be Checkpoint 1, Checkpoint 2 and then Checkpoint 3. I have to use initValue in subsequent calls to other services after Checkpoint 3.

But I'm getting Checkpoint 1, Checkpoint 3 and then Checkpoint 2.

Could someone tell me whats happening here and how can I get what I'm expecting.

I tried using block() but that gives me
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-8`

I've tried using doOnNext(), map and then subscribe() but none of them seem to work.

Comment: `subscribe` proceeds asynchronously, when the result is provided, that's why it may go after the _checkpoint 3_. And you cannot (and shouldn't) block or stop the execution in another way inside a reactor thread, because that would break the reactor

Comment: More explanation about subscribe and how to avoid it (short answer: propagate Reactor API, and transform values using map/flatMap, etc.) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500608/2678097

Comment: @amanin Thanks. Could you elaborate a bit, please? I got the point that Subscribe does the async thing and should avoid it or more appropriately it doesn't fit my use case. After looking where pointed me. I tried this [link] (https://pl.kotl.in/f2zD-sJqk?theme=darcula). But did not help me. It was complaining `Map` is never used as a `Publisher`.

Answer (score 0):

See the javadoc on Mono.subscribe():

```
Keep in mind that since the sequence can be asynchronous, this will immediately return control to the calling thread. This can give the impression the consumer is not invoked when executing in a main thread or a unit test for instance.
```

In your codes, when the `response` is a async mono, the callback will be executed on another thread, even if you used Mono.block(). You can log `Thread.currentThread.getName()` to see the thread names of the callback and the caller.